# Integrate GoogleMaps with Mapbox iOS sdk

Tags: ios, google-maps, mapbox

I'm using MapBox for a iPad app and we want to use various image sources for the map imagery.

Is there a way to get google map tiles and show them in MapBox?

We could construct the url's to get the tiles directly but google will block you if you do this, because we wouldn't be using the official API.

Is there any other option to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically possible, but Google's terms of service don't allow display of their tiles outside of their own software frameworks.

Comment: This is exactly what I found out too. And searching through their issues I found that they aren't interested in changing that. Too bad, I will have to drop support for Google maps.